# Override both _renderItem and _renderMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I override _renderItem for only `#global-search`?

```
$("#global-search").autocomplete({
   //       
})._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
   var self = this;
   ul.append('<table class="ac-search-table"></table>');
   $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
     self._renderItem( ul.find("table"), item );
   });
});
```

Comment: You wanr to override `_renderItem` or `_renderMenu` here?

Comment: Both, I have it working like so: $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = ... and ..._renderItem BUT I have multiple AC's on the page and only want one of them to have their functions overridden.

Comment: Then I suppose it's better to follow the approach I've shown in my answer. You can define some generic functionality in your own methods, then override it with instance methods.

Comment: Please help on the following issue
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33278419/5176876

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remember that you can address the particular instance of the widget created by jQuery UI factory method (`_create`) via `data`:

```
var widgetInst = $("#global-search").autocomplete({}).data('ui-autocomplete');
```

... or, since jQuery UI 1.12, via [instance()](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.12/autocomplete/#method-instance) helper method:

```
var widgetInst = $("#global-search").autocomplete('instance');
```

Thus you're able to override its methods with your own:

```
widgetInst._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  var self = this;
  ul.append('<table class="ac-search-table"></table>');
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    self._renderItem( ul.find("table"), item );
  });
};
```

Comment: The last line of the widgetInst.renderMenu should be changed from "});" to "};" (sorry, I would have edited it myself, but SO has a horrible policy of requiring 6 characters or more for an edit)

Comment: Hello, this solution still working ? I try it with no sucess

Comment: @user Which version of jQuery UI is used, and what exactly is 'no success'?

Comment: @raina77ow, I find a solution. It depends on the jQuery UI version i'm using, like you are asking me here. Instead of writting  `.data('ui-autocomplete')` i have to write `.data('autocomplete')`. Notice the absence of characters **ui-** in my own. Thanks anyway guy

Comment: If memory serves me well, that was the way ('autocomplete') this answer was written originally - but someone has told me that newest version switched to the prefixed call. It was about 4 years ago, so I'm afraid, all that means you're using way too old version of jQuery UI. )

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can override the `_renderItem` function so that it does some object comparison internally and either calls the original `_renderItem` function or executes your custom code.
2. You can create a new widget that inherits from `autocomplete` and override the functions there.