# JQuery UI autocomplete alphabetical ordering followed by matches in other words

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on JQueryUI autocomplete and would like a slightly different behavior than the default. I have an array of strings:

```
var json = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "Little Rock", "RockFord", "Rhode Island"];
```

I would like the following results when I input the following to autocomplete.

Type: **"R"**

**Actual Result:**

Little Rock

Rhode Island

RockFord

**Expected Result:**

Rhode Island

RockFord

Little Rock

Type: **Rock**

**Actual Result:**

Little Rock

RockFord

**Expected Result:**

RockFord

Little Rock

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/71/)

I would like the results to be ordered alphabetically first followed by matches in other words. I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908677/sort-the-values-in-the-jquery-autocomplete) but that only gets me the alphabetical ordering. When I type in "Rock" I would get only RockFord.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `._renderMenu` , `$.grep()`

```js
var json = ["Alabama",
  "Alaska",
  "Arizona",
  "Arkansas",
  "California",
  "Colorado",
  "Connecticut",
  "Delaware",
  "Florida",
  "Georgia",
  "Hawaii",
  "Idaho",
  "Illinois",
  "Indiana",
  "Iowa",
  "Kansas",
  "Kentucky",
  "Little Rock",
  "Louisiana",
  "Maine",
  "Maryland",
  "Massachusetts",
  "Michigan",
  "Minnesota",
  "Mississippi",
  "Missouri",
  "Montana",
  "Nebraska",
  "Nevada",
  "New Hampshire",
  "New Jersey",
  "New Mexico",
  "New York",
  "North Carolina",
  "North Dakota",
  "Ohio",
  "Oklahoma",
  "Oregon",
  "Pennsylvania",
  "RockFord",
  "Rhode Island",
  "South Carolina",
  "South Dakota",
  "Tennessee",
  "Texas",
  "Utah",
  "Vermont",
  "Virginia",
  "Washington",
  "West Virginia",
  "Wisconsin",
  "Wyoming",
];

json.sort();

$("input").autocomplete({
  source: json
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  var that = this;
  var val = that.element.val();
  $.each($.grep(items, function(value, key) {
    return new RegExp(val.toLowerCase())
           .test(value.value.toLowerCase().slice(0, val.length))
  }), function(index, item) {
    that._renderItemData(ul, item);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<input type="text" />
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/75/

---

See also [`_renderMenu(ul, items)`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) , [jQueryUI: how can I custom-format the Autocomplete plug-in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results) , [Override both _renderItem and _renderMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072487/override-both-renderitem-and-rendermenu)

Comment: Thank for your reply, but it does not always work, I tried expanding the array to include 50 US states. Example typing R or M etc does not return expected results. http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/74/

Comment: Thank you so much. it's work perfectly .

Comment: Its not duplicated! Its different